# Need help debugging C code

Tags: c, debugging

Just learnt C this week. My task is to take a large big integer input from the user, store it into a struct Integer, and make a function to print out the appropriate struct integer to the standard output. The program works as such, but as soon as it gives the output, it stops responding. I dont get any direct error in the compiler and cannot figure out what is wrong. Any other advice/tips to improve upon programming style would also be really appreciated :)

```
// Header Files Go Here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function Declarations Go Here
struct integer * convert_integer(char * stringInt);
void printer(struct integer * p);

struct integer {
    int * arr;
    int length;
};

// Main Program
int main() {
    char * x;
    x = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10000);
    printf("Enter a small string\n");
    scanf("%s",x);
    int j = 0;
    struct integer * book1;
    book1 = convert_integer(x);
    printer(book1);
    return 0;
}

// Function Definitions Go Here  
struct integer * convert_integer(char * stringInt) {
    struct integer * x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    int j = 0;
    while (stringInt[j] != '\0') {
        if (stringInt[j] < 48 || stringInt[j] >= 57) {
            printf("Invalid input. Enter a number ");
            return;
        }
        x->arr[j] = stringInt[j] - 48;
        j++;
    }
    x->length = j;
    printf("\n the length is %d\n", x->length);
    return x;
}

void printer(struct integer * p) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < p->length) {
        printf("%d", p->arr[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better solution to using a dynamic array: use a stack and implement it with a linked list. Reason being, you are always only interested in one digit at a time.

Comment: @JacobPollack, Fair enough, I will do that soon. But i think its important to understand why I am facing this sort of error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding this answer because NPE was not clear enough.

---

The are a few errors in this program but I would say the pressing one is in the function `convert_integer`. You are doing the following:

```
struct integer* x= malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
```

... but that is incorrect. You are requesting too many bytes of memory for `x` considering its data type (nothing *really* wrong with that), however you are not requesting blocks of memory for `arr`. It needs to be as follows:

```
struct integer *x = malloc( sizeof( struct integer ) );

x->arr = malloc( sizeof( int ) * c );
```

... where `c` is some constant (in your case 100?). Make sure that when you `free` this structure you first `free` the `arr` and then `free` the structure, or else you will have a memory leak.

Something else I noticed you are not doing, **always check the result of a system call**. You are not checking to see if `malloc` returned an invalid memory block.

Comment: I used to think if i assign memory of a struct, i would automatically assign memory for whats stored in it. Which doesnt make sense that I think of it now . Thanks a lot for your help :)

I will add a test statement for all my mallocs now !

Comment: @AkashRupela, choose an answer and up vote it so that others who run into the same problem as you are able to fix it.

Comment: Yeah. I tried it but cudnt upvote cuz i m new and i dont have reputation yet. I have bookmarked and will upvote once i have the power to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a prototype for `printer` on top.  The `if` statement validating the number should be

```
if(stringInt[j]<48 || stringInt[j]>57)  // > instead of >=
```

It will make more sense to write it as

```
if ( stringInt[j] < '0' || stringInt[j] > '9' )
```

If you know about `isdigit` function, you can use that as well.

You are allocating memory for a string with 10000 characters.  That seems like an overkill.  You can allocate memory for 256 characters and that should be plenty.  You also should deallocate memory before executing `return` using the statement `free (x);`

You need to allocate space for `arr` inside the `convert_integer` function.  Your allocations should be:

```
struct integer* x= malloc(sizeof(integer)); x->arr = malloc ( sizeof(int) * 256 );
```

Comment: Thanks for that :). I did 10000 because eventually I would like to test my program on a larger input too.  These were helpful but doesnt really solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
struct integer* x= malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);;
```

you are allocating memory for the structure (i.e. the pointer and the int), but not for the array.

The moment you try to assign to `x->arr[j]`, you have [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: there is no environment where the `struct integer` would require more than n * 100 bytes (where n is commonly 4 or 8), it is only composed of a pointer and an integer. He is allocating more memory than needing but that should not be a pressing issue.

Comment: @wildplasser, that still is not an issue. I see what NPE is getting at though, he's saying that he should of also `malloc` a block of memory of sufficient size for `arr`. But the issue is not the line he specified, it's the line the OP did not include (`malloc`ing a block of memory for `arr`).

Comment: how should i malloc for arr? within the struct or in the main?

Comment: @AkashRupela, you need to do `x = malloc( sizeof( struct integer ) )` and under it do `x->arr = malloc( sizeof( int ) * 100 )`.

Comment: YES. Thankyou so much guys (y)
I m getting to understand more of how memory works :)

Comment: @AkashRupela, I added an answer to better communicate this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing at the line

```
x->arr[j]=stringInt[j]-48;
```

The reason is the way you allocate your memory slice:

```
struct integer* x= malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
```

This allocates a slice of `n*100` bytes and stores a pointer to that slice in `x`. What you want to do is the following:

```
struct integer *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
x->arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

That allocates the memory needed to store the `integer` structure `x` and it allocates memory to store 100 integers and assigns it to `x->arr`. With your code, `x->arr` is not initialized and thus has random values in it (more precisely: The values are those that were stored at that memory location before).

After finished using the allocated memory, you should also free it:

```
free(x->arr);
free(x);
```